# VS Code code navigation doesn’t work after adding compilerOptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, you can navigate to the file where  the original code is by Ctrl + Click.

However, it doesn’t work properly after I added compilerOptions in jsconfig.json in my project.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"],
       ...
```

Does anyone have this similar issues? Should I install vs code extension to solve this?

Comment: i am facing the same problem. DId you get any solution?

Comment: i have also same issue